# How to do default and localised routes in Sapper i18n?

Tags: internationalization, svelte, sapper

I'm stuck a bit making my Sapper app work right! I want to allow users to visit my website like this:

example.com - default en lang
example.com/blog - default en lang

example.com/de - german page
example.com/de/blog - blog in german

example.com/ru - russian page
example.com/ru/blog - blog in russian

Question taken from [Github](https://github.com/kaisermann/sapper-template-i18n/issues/9)

Comment: Sveltekit soultion would be interesting too.